# inventory by resources and classes in GDSCRIPT

Tags: gdscript, godot4

I am currently making an inventory system, where an array has 20 slots of the inventorySlots class:

```
extends Resource

class_name InventorySlot

@export var item: InventoryItem
@export var amount = 0
```

and each item has its class
InventoryItem:

```
extends Resource

class_name InventoryItem

@export var name: String = ""
@export var itemtype: String = ""
@export var texture: Texture2D
@export var MaxStackeable: int
```

without after assigning to the PlayerInventory resource an array of 20 slots and each one is of the InventorySlot class.

I can't make the functions to move the position items, since these "inherit" what they had initially and when I delete it by putting "null", or its attributes in an empty string "", it will inherit those values in the position That this.

```
extends Resource

class_name Inventory

@export var slots: Array[InventorySlot]
var maxStackeable = 20
signal updated
var signalis = false
func insert(item: InventoryItem, maxAmount: int):
    for slot in slots:
        if slot.item == item:
            if slot.item.MaxStackeable:
                maxStackeable = slot.item.MaxStackeable
            if slot.amount < maxStackeable:
                slot.amount += 1
                updated.emit()
                return

    for i in range(slots.size()):
        if !slots[i].item:
            slots[i].item = item
            slots[i].amount = 1
            updated.emit()
            return

func pickFromSlot(slotItem, posIndex, amount):
    if signalis:
        print("ya habia pasado: ", posIndex)
        signalis = false
    if slots[posIndex] == slotItem:
        if slots[posIndex].amount > 0:
            slots[posIndex].amount -= amount
            if slots[posIndex].amount == 0:
                slots[posIndex].item = null
            updated.emit()
            return

func putIntoSlot(target_item, target_slot, maxAmount):
    if target_item:
        if target_item.MaxStackeable != 0:
            maxStackeable = target_item.MaxStackeable

        if slots[target_slot].item == target_item:
            if slots[target_slot].amount < maxStackeable and maxAmount < maxStackeable:
                slots[target_slot].amount += maxAmount
                updated.emit()
                return true
            else:
                return false

        if !slots[target_slot].item:
            slots[target_slot].item = target_item
            slots[target_slot].amount = maxAmount
            signalis = true
            updated.emit()
            print("primer item pasado: ", target_slot)
            return true
        else:
            false
    else:
        return false

func useItemCollectable(index, item):
    if slots[index].item.name == item:
        if slots[index].amount == 1:
            slots[index].item = null
            slots[index].amount = 0
            updated.emit()
        else:
            slots[index].amount -= 1
            updated.emit()
```